# How t Remove Labels from comment Box

Tags: comments, forms

I am learning to create custom theme. I have enabled default WordPress Comment for but I dont  like how labels are appearing.

Is there any way to remove labels and put placeholder text instead?

Attached is an image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can look into comment_form() function. You can modify your fields and pass into this function to generate the comment form. Typically it is used within comments.php file.

Comment: Found solution. This code will help. Here is the help https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_form_fields/